# Arguments in Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I try to manipulate pictures with imageick. On the CLI I use this working fine command:

```
C:\ProgrammeNoSetup\ImageMagick-7.1.0-62-portable-Q16-HDRI-x64\magick.exe D:\orG\3.08_10-02_1.jpg -resize 1200x1200 D:\orG\output\3.08_10-02_1.jpg
```

But I try to that in a powershell script (test.ps1) with this code:

```
$CMD = 'C:\ProgrammeNoSetup\ImageMagick-7.1.0-62-portable-Q16-HDRI-x64\magick.exe'
$arg2 = 'D:\orG\3.08_10-02_1.jpg'
$arg3 = '-resize 1200x1200'
$arg4 = 'D:\orG\output\3.08_10-02_1.jpg'

& $CMD $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
```

Im getting this error: magick.exe: unrecognized option `-resize 1200x1200' at CLI arg 2 @ fatal/magick-cli.c/ProcessCommandOptions/659.

I have also tried:

```
$CMD = 'C:\ProgrammeNoSetup\ImageMagick-7.1.0-62-portable-Q16-HDRI-x64\magick.exe'
$arg1 = 'convert'
$arg2 = 'D:\orG\3.08_10-02_1.jpg'
$arg3 = '-resize 1200x1200'
$arg4 = 'D:\orG\output\3.08_10-02_1.jpg'

& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
```

But the error is similar: convert: unrecognized option `-resize 1200x1200' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2686.

If I remove the option "-resize 1200x1200". There is now error message and the command is writing the file (without resize) to the output folder. So I think, that I have a problem with my option, but I can't find it. I have invested several hours and als tried with the @-symbol for arguments, without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to **separate argument name and value**, otherwise `-resize 1200x1200` will be passed as a single token, but native executables usually expect argument name and value to be separate tokens (unless the syntax is without whitespace, e. g. `-name:value`).

```sh
$CMD = 'C:\ProgrammeNoSetup\ImageMagick-7.1.0-62-portable-Q16-HDRI-x64\magick.exe'
$arg1 = 'convert'
$arg2 = 'D:\orG\3.08_10-02_1.jpg'
$arg3 = '-resize', '1200x1200'
               # |<-- inserted comma here
$arg4 = 'D:\orG\output\3.08_10-02_1.jpg'

& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
```

This turns `$arg3` into an array of two strings, which PowerShell passes as separate argument tokens. This is also called *splatting* and is only done when calling native executables (for PowerShell commands you have to use the `@` splatting operator).

Another, more concise way:

```sh
$CMD = 'C:\ProgrammeNoSetup\ImageMagick-7.1.0-62-portable-Q16-HDRI-x64\magick.exe'

# Create an array of arguments
$imArgs = @(
    'convert'
    'D:\orG\3.08_10-02_1.jpg'
    '-resize', '1200x1200'
    'D:\orG\output\3.08_10-02_1.jpg' 
)

# Call native command, which splats argument array.
& $CMD $imArgs

# Alternatively you can be explicit about splatting:
& $CMD @imArgs
```

Make sure you don't name the variable `$args` which is a reserved PowerShell variable.

---

As an aside, if you want to be able to call ImageMagick without having to hardcode its path in all of your scripts, add the installation directory of ImageMagick ("C:\ProgrammeNoSetup\ImageMagick-7.1.0-62-portable-Q16-HDRI-x64") to the `PATH` environment variable.

You could then call ImageMagick simply by specifying the name of its executable:

```sh
magick @imArgs
```